# Ruby ActiveModel::Validation and ActiveModel::Errors setup function for validation

Tags: ruby, validation

I've been tasked with writing a function to validate that the first name and surname are not the same in the code below. I have to use ActiveModel::Validation and ActiveModel::Errors and if the two names are the same it should give an error message "Nope".

I have very little ruby experience, but here's my attempt:

```
require 'active_model'

class Person
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    validate :test
    validates_presence_of :first
    validates_presence_of :last

    def initialize(first, last)
        @first = first
        @last = last
    end

    def test
        errors.add_to_base("Nope") if @first == @last
    end

end

a = Person.new("James", "James")
b = Person.new("James")
```

So I get an error message when I try to instantiate `b` but that's just a Ruby error because my function is missing arguments. I'm sure this is probably pretty simple, but I'd be really grateful for any help.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The question is how do I get the function to validate that both the names are not the same, and also how do I validate the presence of the first and second name?

Comment: Are you using rails? Or just ActiveModel? Anyhow, instead of missing last name you can pass `nil`: `Person.new("James", nil)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution to this, what I was looking for was:

```
require 'active_model'

class Person
include ActiveModel::Validations
attr_accessor :first, :last
validate :first_does_not_equal_last

def first_does_not_equal_last
  if @first == @last
    self.errors[:base] << "First cannot be the same as Last"
  end
end

def initialize(first, last)
    @first = first
    @last = last
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel for more info:

```
require 'active_model'

class TestValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:base] = "First and last can't be the same" if record.first.presence == record.last.presence
  end
end

class Person
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :first, :last

    validates_presence_of :first, :last
    validates_with TestValidator
end

p = Person.new(first: "Nick", last: "Nick")
puts p.valid? # => false
puts p.errors.full_messages # => First and last can't be the same

p = Person.new(first: "Nick", last: "Doe")
puts p.valid? # => true
```